# how to align a child div to bottom on a scrollable parent div

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox

I am working on a chat system and I have a scrollable `parent` div and a `child` div that contains the messages such that:

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse; /*This works fine in Opera and Chrome, but not in Firefox and Edge*/
}

#child {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, I need the child div to start from the bottom and go up as message divs are added, for this I do a `flex-direction: column-reverse` in the scrollable parent div and this works well in browsers Opera and Chrome but disable scrolling in Firefox and Edge

My problem is that when using flex in the div with scroll, automatically in Firefox and Edge the scroll stops working

Comment: You can try to use `position: absolute;` on the child div.
and I am do not sure I understand you, how its look like before and after?

Comment: do you try to reverse the scroll ?  like this ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WNeROpR